# what is daylight correction in php?

Tags: php, dst

i am new to php.
I want to know what is daylight correction in php.
Can anybody post some information about this along with some examples.It will be very much helpful for me.

Comment: google this and find better links

Comment: It means time-related functions will honor the DST settings of the used timezone.

Comment: i tried but couldnt find it......

Answer (score 1):

In some countries, there is [**Daylight saving time**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) *(for example, in France, we're switching in summer time this next night)*.

PHP is *(more or less)* able to work with that ; dealing with the fact that not all countries have DST, and that not all countries switch to DST at the same time.